# How to verify the order of mocks without explicitly defining the order of methods?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

Here is the **method to be tested**:

```
protected void myMethod(final MyObject object) {

    object.setX(...);
    object.setY(...);

    myObjectRepository.update(object);
}
```

In order to verify the order of calls -so that the repository is called after all setter calls- i needed to make a mock of MyObject (since inOrder works just with mocks). **At the end it should look like this**:

```
@Mock
private MyObjectRepository myObjectRepositoryMock;

@Test
public void testMyMethod() {
    MyObject myObjectMock = mock(MyObject.class);

    InOrder inOrder = Mockito.inOrder(myObjectMock, myObjectRepositoryMock);

    // Run Test .....

    inOrder.verify(myObjectMock);
    inOrder.verify(myObjectRepositoryMock).update(myObjectMock);
}
```

.. but we see this exception:

```
.. UnfinishedVerificationException
Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
...
Example of correct verification:
    verify(mock).doSomething()
```

Since i do not have to verify the order of setter calls, i would just group them together and say sth like "first this mock, than that method of that mock with that argument should be called"..

**I do not want to define the exact order like this**:

```
    inOrder.verify(myObjectMock).setX(..);
    inOrder.verify(myObjectMock).setY(..);
    inOrder.verify(myObjectRepositoryMock).update(myObjectMock);
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can verify the fields with `assertEquals` inside of `doAnswer()`

```
object.setX(-1);
Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() { 
        public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable { 
                assertEquals(1, object.getX());
                return null; 
        } 
}).when(myObjectRepositoryMock).update(object);
```

That way, the order of calls doesn't matter; all that matters is that at the time of the `update()` call, the correct value is in the correct place.

Comment: I have also just found out that! Thank you!